# VS Code cannot open source "graphics.h", although "C:/MinGW/libs/**" is added to includePath

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, header-files, bgi

So I'm trying to import [this](http://www.codewithc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/WinBGIm_Library6_0_Nov2005.zip) library to my code, so I copied the header files to my MinGW/include folder, then copied the library files to MinGW/lib, and finally added "C:/MinGW/include/**" to my includePaths in the C/C++ config file. Still thou, I'm getting the error that this header doesn't exist

Comment: The link just returns to this question.  What is a `.g` file?  Is that a typo?  C headers generally/always have a `.h` file extension.

Comment: It's a typo. I just can't type sometimes